# server error hosting - directory not found

Tags: laravel, hosting, namecheap

I've just deployed a Laravel project on namecheap. But when I try to show the home page it showed me "directory not existing". the directory exists in my laptop.

[image]

Comment: Does that directory exist in your server hosting at namecheap?  isn't your home page running there instead your laptop?

Comment: the home page shows that message. witch exists on my laptop, not on the server.

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. Please delete your question here and re-ask it there.

Comment: run " php artisan optimize:clear " and add permission 755 to storage folder and bootstrap/cache folders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted the config.php file, in bootstrap/cache folder and it works.